# m2clipse maven with Android and ActionBarSherlock

Tags: android, maven, actionbarsherlock

I'm new to the all Maven.. In my understanding it should help me with keeping an order with my dependencies..
I'm trying to make it work using the m2clipse plugin and make it work with Android.
(I used this site to do so: http://looksok.wordpress.com/2012/05/12/use-maven-with-android-project/)

I have updated my existing project to a maven project.
and added dependency to the actionbarsherlock project.
My pom.xml file looks like this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>myproject</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>apk</packaging>
<name>myproject</name>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
        <artifactId>android</artifactId>
        <version>1.6_r2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.actionbarsherlock</groupId>
        <artifactId>actionbarsherlock</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.1</version>
        <type>apklib</type>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
            <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <sdk>
                    <!-- platform or api level (api level 4 = platform 1.6)-->
                    <platform>10</platform>
                </sdk>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**I have a few questions:**

1. "4.0.0" - this is a version for what?

2. "1.6_r2" - this is the minimum android version that my app support? or this is the android version to compile? I think it is the version to copile to, but in this case - what should I do if I want to compile to the Google API? If I want to use the google maps for instance..

3. 3.2.0 - this is a version for what?

4. 10 - this is the platform for android. But what is it stands for? Again, the minimum sdk to support? the target sdk? What is it?:-)

5. It looks like that it doesn't matter what version of android I'm writing in the pom.xml file, the AndroidManifest file is updating. Should be update when I'm updating the project with maven? (when I'm clicking "Update project")

6. Last question - When I added the actionbarsherlock dependency I get this error:
"dependency=[com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:apklib:4.3.1:compile] not found in workspace", why isn't it working??

Thank you all :-)

Answer (score 0):

1. It is your maven model version
2. version of jar that you want to use during the build process.
3. version of "android-maven-plugin"
4. these are the configurations to use "android-maven-plugin"
5. Don't really know what mi8 be wrong over here. :)
6. May be you din't update the project after updating your pom, because that when new jars are downloaded and loaded in the build path.

Comment: I didn't get the answer to the questions 4 and 5.. can you explain a little bit more?
And for question number 6, I didn't updated the project: right click on the project -> Maven -> Update project..
What else could the problem be?

Comment: Still question 4+5 stay the same - hope that you could help me with them. About question 6, when I delete the "<type>apklib</type>" it downloads the jar file and every thing is ok. But I have read about the apklib, and it should mark that this as a library android project. What isn't is working like it should be?

Comment: try compiling your project from command prompt, sometimes the m2eclipse doesn't work.